# Adding several layers to table of contents in ArcMap using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layers

I am already able to add individual layers to ArcMap table of contents using the following codes:

```
# Adding the layer to the table of contents
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
path = os.path.abspath(LayerName)
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(path)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer)
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
del mxd, addLayer
```

However I can't figure out how I can load multiple layers at the same time. For example the following codes don't work and only only of the layers gets added:

```
# Adding mulitple Layers to the table of contents
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
path = os.path.abspath(FirstLayer)
path2 = os.path.abspath(SecondLayer)
path3 = os.path.abspath(ThirdLayer)
.
.
.
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(path)
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(path2)
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(path3)
.
.
.
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer)
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
del mxd, addLayer
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You change your addLayer variable twice before adding it to your data frame, so of course only the last one gets added. Use the AddLayer function after setting every addLayer variable:

```
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(path)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer)

addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(path2)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer)

addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(path3)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer)
.
.
.
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer)
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
del mxd, addLayer
```